# How to get html tag with dynamic text and also having a span in it

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, tags

I got stuck to generate relative xpath of an element while automating a website.

Site Name: `www.magicbricks.com/forum`

Please visit this website and try to find a locality in Search bar with text 'Sai Park'.

Lots of result came out in the list below the search box. Now I have to select 'Project Sai Park, Pune'.

I did try to generate the xpath like this:

```
//span[text()='Sai Park']/parent::a[text()=', Pune']
```

But this code is only working if there is no text present before span tag in anchor tag.

The text of a tag depends on what you are searching (searched text will be treated as span text)

Here is the tag:

```
<a onclick="discussionPageSearchResult('48633','Project Sai Park |Pune','PROJECTS');" id="ui-id-151" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Project <span>Sai Park</span>, Pune</a>
```

Can you please let me know how to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Show a stripped down version of how exactly the HTML looks you're trying to parse.

Comment: <a onclick="discussionPageSearchResult('48633','Project Sai Park |Pune','PROJECTS');" id="ui-id-151" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Project <span>Sai Park</span>, Pune</a>

Comment: Please add that to your question and format it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following XPath expression should do what you want:

```
//a[normalize-space()="Project Sai Park, Pune"]
```

It selects the `a` tag if the text within that tag equals *Project Sai Park, Pune*, after normalizing any whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks alot Markus, can you please let me know is there any learning website from where I can learn to generate perfect xpaths like you did?

Comment: @deepak.mr888 I'm sorry, but I don't know any such website, but Google is your friend there. Me myself, I got started on XPath and XSLT using the XSLT 1.0 Pocket Reference from O'Reilly. From there on it was mostly learning by doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

//span[text()='Sai Park']/parent::a[contains(text(),'Pune')]

Answer (score 0):

If you use java, use the below solution:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='project-sai-park']"));

//scroll to that element
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

element.click();
```

hope this will help you and let me know what happens.